# javascript find function not working

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript, find

I need to get a find function working. I get an error that I'm not sure how to fix.
I can get an example to work in a playground based on the mdn site:
[https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find](https://mdn%20link)

Any direction appreciated

[image]

js:

```
    console.log('taskResourceList--++++++++++1111111++++++++---', JSON.stringify(this.taskResourceList));
//START UPDATED
    this.mrListForUpdate.forEach(function(item, index) { //UPDATED
                console.log('taskResourceList--++++++++++2222222++++++++---', JSON.stringify(this.taskResourceList));
//END UPDATED
                console.log('Id  -- ', item.Id);
        
                const tr = this.taskResourceList.find(({ Id }) => Id === item.Id);
```

output:

```
taskResourceList--++++++++++++++++++--- [{"Id":"a2Y3S00000GNnokUAD","Mission__c":"a2b3S000000GVBCQA4","Status__c":"Coordinating","Quantity__c":76,"Quantity_Filled__c":4,"Resource_Name__c":"Portable batterys","Description__c":"dfgs gdsf sdfs  sdg"},{"Id":"a2Y3S00000GNnonUAD","Mission__c":"a2b3S000000GVBCQA4","Status__c":"Coordinating","Quantity__c":57,"Quantity_Filled__c":3,"Resource_Name__c":"Water,"Description__c":"rh r"},{"Id":"a2Y3S00000GNnoqUAD","Mission__c":"a2b3S000000GVBCQA4","Status__c":"Coordinating","Quantity__c":95,"Quantity_Filled__c":5,"Resource_Name__c":"Hauling","Description__c":"sdgh r wr h"}]
Id  --  a2Y3S00000GNnokUAD
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a `function` changes the scope of `this` to whatever the function is being run against. It's important to use Arrow functions instead:

```
this.mrListForUpdate.forEach((item, index) => {
    const tr = this.taskResourceList.find(({ Id }) => Id === item.Id);
});
```

Comment: Ah crap didn't see the outer forEach... because of the formatting. So `item` is in scope. (or would be if they'd used an arrow function)

Comment: I added it later @CasparHarmer. My bad :{

Comment: @sfdcfox so I'm not going mad after all!! My original answer was good. :(